# Effective Access is showing wrong in Windows server 2012 R2 Only

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list

I am facing some strange issue. Please find below print-screen, which is of Effective Access on Window server 2012 R2 for Statement folder for Security Group

Below is the print-screen for the same folder i.e Statement in windows server 2003 for same Security Group.
[image]

In Windows server 2012 R2, no access for the same security group is shown, but if we check for the same folder in windows server 2003, we can check that the same security group has the access.
Please find below print-screen for windows server 2003
[image]

But if we check access for the user account in that group in Windows server 2012 r2 and Windows server 2003 than it is showing proper.

Only the problem is with the security group, on both the Server it is showing different.

Thanks & Regards,

Param

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 enables resource SID compression by default. It is incompatible with Windows Server 2003 and legacy storage appliances.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2774190/resource-sid-compression-in-windows-server-2012-may-cause-authorization-problems-on-devices-that-do-not-support-resource-sid-compression